# How to count the amount of words in a text file in Lua

Tags: string, count, lua, cpu-word, read-write

I was wanting to ask what the steps are to creating a Lua program that would count the amount of words in a .txt file? I'm only familiar with how to count characters and not strings.

Comment: counting words accurately is tricky, there are so many edge cases with hyphens and em dashes etc. A simple one might use [string.gfind](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html)

Comment: Check out the book Programming in Lua (which has a free version online) - program to count the number of characters, words, and lines in a file: http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.1.html

Comment: @rpattiso, `string.gfind` has been renamed `string.gmatch` since then.

Comment: @lhf sorry, looks like 5.0 was the last appearance of `string.gfind`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sequence of nonspace characters is a good approximation to what a word is.

In that case, this simple code counts the words in a string `s`:

```
_,n = s:gsub("%S+","")
print(n)
```

This works because `gsub` returns the number of substitutions made as a second result. This count is rarely used, and sometimes even a minor annoyance, but in this case it's exactly what is needed.